# How to change Rails route helpers to match our will?

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2, helper

I generated a scaffold with following command :

```
rails generate scaffold indice valeur:decimal date:date
```

I use the gorgeous gem "[rails-translate-routes](https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes)" to translate URLs(path) to french with I18 internationalization.

I as well put the indices controller into a **namespace** (app/controller/catalogs/pub_indices_controller.rb) with my **config/route.rb** :

```
  namespace :catalogs do
    resources :pub_indices
  end
```

The resulting routes are incorrect because of Rails inflection. It use "index" instead of "indice" for singular, though I use "indice" to generate and my model is called pub_indice.rb :

```
             catalogs_pub_indices_fr GET    /catalogues/indices(.:format)                      catalogs/pub_indices#index {:locale=>"fr"}
             catalogs_pub_indices_en GET    /en/catalogs/pub_indices(.:format)                 catalogs/pub_indices#index {:locale=>"en"}
                                     POST   /catalogues/indices(.:format)                      catalogs/pub_indices#create {:locale=>"fr"}
                                     POST   /en/catalogs/pub_indices(.:format)                 catalogs/pub_indices#create {:locale=>"en"}
           new_catalogs_pub_index_fr GET    /catalogues/indices/nouveau(.:format)              catalogs/pub_indices#new {:locale=>"fr"}
           new_catalogs_pub_index_en GET    /en/catalogs/pub_indices/new(.:format)             catalogs/pub_indices#new {:locale=>"en"}
          edit_catalogs_pub_index_fr GET    /catalogues/indices/:id/modifier(.:format)         catalogs/pub_indices#edit {:locale=>"fr"}
          edit_catalogs_pub_index_en GET    /en/catalogs/pub_indices/:id/edit(.:format)        catalogs/pub_indices#edit {:locale=>"en"}
               catalogs_pub_index_fr GET    /catalogues/indices/:id(.:format)                  catalogs/pub_indices#show {:locale=>"fr"}
               catalogs_pub_index_en GET    /en/catalogs/pub_indices/:id(.:format)             catalogs/pub_indices#show {:locale=>"en"}
                                     PUT    /catalogues/indices/:id(.:format)                  catalogs/pub_indices#update {:locale=>"fr"}
                                     PUT    /en/catalogs/pub_indices/:id(.:format)             catalogs/pub_indices#update {:locale=>"en"}
                                     DELETE /catalogues/indices/:id(.:format)                  catalogs/pub_indices#destroy {:locale=>"fr"}
                                     DELETE /en/catalogs/pub_indices/:id(.:format)             catalogs/pub_indices#destroy {:locale=>"en"}
```

So I googled a bit and discover the word "inflector"...
So I used the trick provided by [official doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-singular-form) in my **config/route.rb** :

```
  ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
    inflect.irregular 'indice', 'indices'
  end
```

And the route helpers look alright :

```
             catalogs_pub_indices_fr GET    /catalogues/indices(.:format)                      catalogs/pub_indices#index {:locale=>"fr"}
             catalogs_pub_indices_en GET    /en/catalogs/pub_indices(.:format)                 catalogs/pub_indices#index {:locale=>"en"}
                                     POST   /catalogues/indices(.:format)                      catalogs/pub_indices#create {:locale=>"fr"}
                                     POST   /en/catalogs/pub_indices(.:format)                 catalogs/pub_indices#create {:locale=>"en"}
          new_catalogs_pub_indice_fr GET    /catalogues/indices/nouveau(.:format)              catalogs/pub_indices#new {:locale=>"fr"}
          new_catalogs_pub_indice_en GET    /en/catalogs/pub_indices/new(.:format)             catalogs/pub_indices#new {:locale=>"en"}
         edit_catalogs_pub_indice_fr GET    /catalogues/indices/:id/modifier(.:format)         catalogs/pub_indices#edit {:locale=>"fr"}
         edit_catalogs_pub_indice_en GET    /en/catalogs/pub_indices/:id/edit(.:format)        catalogs/pub_indices#edit {:locale=>"en"}
              catalogs_pub_indice_fr GET    /catalogues/indices/:id(.:format)                  catalogs/pub_indices#show {:locale=>"fr"}
              catalogs_pub_indice_en GET    /en/catalogs/pub_indices/:id(.:format)             catalogs/pub_indices#show {:locale=>"en"}
                                     PUT    /catalogues/indices/:id(.:format)                  catalogs/pub_indices#update {:locale=>"fr"}
                                     PUT    /en/catalogs/pub_indices/:id(.:format)             catalogs/pub_indices#update {:locale=>"en"}
                                     DELETE /catalogues/indices/:id(.:format)                  catalogs/pub_indices#destroy {:locale=>"fr"}
                                     DELETE /en/catalogs/pub_indices/:id(.:format)             catalogs/pub_indices#destroy {:locale=>"en"}
```

But Rails refuse to accept routes using "indice" like this : **new_catalogs_pub_indice_path**

Instead it accept the incorrect form : **new_catalogs_pub_index_path** though rake route is saying something different.

Could anyone explain me what am I doing wrong ? (I wish Rails didn't used this singular/plural form. It would have been so much simpler *sigh*)

===== UPDATE =====

Ok, I was to quick on this question. After some more search, Il realized my "inflector" code should rather be placed into **config/initializers/inflections.rb** :

```
  ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
    inflect.irregular 'indice', 'indices'
  end
```

The [official doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-singular-form) just explain how. It doesn't tell where. So as the context was talking about config/route.rb I thought about puting my code into route.rb but that is wrong.

Official doc is lacking explanation about inflector. That's a shame ^^
Be carefull guys ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as I explained in my update.

route helpers syntax may be changed by using infelctor in **config/initializers/inflections.rb**.

The [official doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-singular-form) shows an example.